# Webscraping "How did you contribute to OpenStreetMap" with rvest

Tags: web-scraping, openstreetmap, rvest

I would like to scrape all the information from the "How did you contribute to OpenStreetMap?" (https://hdyc.neis-one.org/). It is necessary to login to OSM in order to gain a user profile.

Since there are quite a lot of profiles that need to be scraped, I want to automatically scrape the list using the rvest package (https://rvest.tidyverse.org/).

So far I attempted to do this:

```r
> library(rvest)

> url <- "https://hdyc.neis-one.org/?mrsensible"
> pgsession <- session(URL)

> pgsession
<session> https://hdyc.neis-one.org/?mrsensible
  Status: 200
  Type:   text/html
  Size:   4245
```

When I tried to read the information of my OSM record with `read_html(url)`, here is what it turns out:

```
> read_html(url)

{html_document}
<html>
[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n<meta ...
[2] <body onload="init();">\n        <div class="copyright">Copyright © <a target="_bl ...
```

So it doesn't really capture the information.

Would it be possible to scrape the data using `rvest` codes?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You may need to use `RSelenum`

Comment: Have you contacted the author/operator of the service? https://twitter.com/pascal_n

Comment: @RichardFairhurst No I haven't but maybe I should do that